# What is the tag usage of [flow]?

Tags: discussion, tag-info

What is the tag usage of [flow](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flow)?

It seems to me it's mostly boundary layer questions.

Would it be better if it's renamed to [boundary-layer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundary-layer)?

---

A [quick search](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22boundary%20layer%22%20is%3Aq) gives 47 results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I would agree.

If not renaming (i.e. a mod makes a synonym), at least getting rid of the tag. It's unclear and not really helpful.