# How best to handle the tags for the boundary layer topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Background (from 2 years ago): [What is the tag usage of [flow]?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3975/14897)

Based on that and its accepted answer: I now created [boundary-layer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundary-layer) including usage guidance in preparation for adding the existing [flow](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flow) as a synonym to it. But then I found that since asking the original question the [laminar-flow](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laminar-flow) **x7** was created. Also [separation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/separation) keeps getting mistaken for flow separation (examples: [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/revisions/90058/1), [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/revisions/58794/1)) and not its intended use of traffic separation.

How best to handle all those?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:

1. Add existing [flow](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flow) as a synonym to [boundary-layer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundary-layer) as previously agreed
2. Add the new [laminar-flow](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laminar-flow) as a synonym to it as well since boundary layer the topic covers:

   - laminar flow
   - and the transition to:
   - turbulent flow
3. Create and add [turbulent-flow](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turbulent-flow) as a synonym to [boundary-layer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boundary-layer) (same reason as #2)
4. Rename [separation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/separation) to [traffic-separation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traffic-separation) to avoid the common mistake

I considered manual retagging; bumping 5 posts a day for a couple of days, but since that won't add the benefits of 2–4 (helping users in finding the main/correct topic), might as well request #1.

Comment: Id be happy to make these changes, but Im afraid I dont know enough about the topic to determine if this is the right suggestion. If those that do weigh in, or a moderator with enough domain knowledge gets there before me all the better

Comment: @Jamiec: Now that you mention it, I reconsidered [flow-separation] (*might* be debatable), and it doesn't even exist now, so I removed its request and kept it more simple. Also happy to wait for more eyes to see this post.

Comment: The [tag:separation] questions mistagged need to be retagged before we rename

Comment: @Jamiec: done (3 further actions) and verified none remain.

Comment: @Jamiec: since Nov, four more cropped up and are now retagged; for your kind action please whenever you have time :)